# Not able to found declaration for mongo:mongo

Tags: spring, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

This is spring-mongo.xml class while deploying I am getting some error. This is my XML.form this xml I am not able to create bean instance of MongoTemplate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<mongo:mongo host="192.1XX.X0.7XX" port="27017" />

<mongo:db-factory dbname="HealthKart" />

<bean id="mappingContext"
      class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext"></bean>

<bean id="defaultMongoTypeMapper"
      class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey" value="null" />
</bean>

<bean id="mappingMongoConverter"
      class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mappingContext" />
    <property name="typeMapper" ref="defaultMongoTypeMapper" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingMongoConverter" />
</bean>
```

I am using spring version 4 and getting the error as, and my server is not starting and not coming up. Tried with different version

```
     Context initialization failed
     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from file [/usr/local/projects/tomcat_api/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/spring/spring-mongo.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 54; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:515)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 54; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:mongo'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:452)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3230)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1911)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:760)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
```

This is the error that I am getting and my server is not coming up.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the below line could be erroneous . Is there an attribute called mongo under the namespace ?

```
<mongo:mongo host="192.168.70.77" port="27017" />
```

If you are just starting out , I would suggest you try Spring Boot with everything preconfigured : https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Just put below lines in your Gradle build file and run the Application class .

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
```